# Dificuldade para montar uma instrução SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho quebrado a cabeça aqui para montar um SQL, quem sabe alguém possa me ajudar.

Estou tentando elaborar um relatório para cobrar o relacionamento de notas que eventualmente foram excluídas.

O usuário cadastra uma nf no sistema que tem como status inicial "relacionado", mas em alguns casos ele precisa excluir essa nf que passa do status "relacionado" para "excluído", e faz uma outra, um novo registro é feito pra aquela mesma nf, com id diferente, porém com o número de nf igual a anterior mas agora com o status "relacionado".

Enfim, queria uma consulta sql que considera-se o último registro de uma nf que tenha status de "excluído".

Por exemplo, tenho a seguinte consulta:

```
 SELECT id, nf, status, date FROM documentos
```

A instrução retorna os seguintes registros:

[image: retorno como é]

Como deveria ser, do resultado acima quero saber somente o último registro de uma determinada nf quando for status "excluído".

[image: retorno como gostaria que fosse]

Estou utilizando o Mysql para fazer a query.

Comment: resumindo, voce quer saber quais notas fiscais foram excluídas e não foram inseridos novamente

Comment: Nota fiscal pelo que sei não pode ser excluída.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acredito que deve ter forma mais simples de fazer isso, mas assim deve funcionar:

```
SELECT u.id, u.nf, u.status, u.date
FROM documentos u
WHERE u.id IN (
    SELECT MAX(d.id)
    FROM documentos d
    GROUP BY d.nf
)
AND u.status = 'EXCLUIDO'
```

O `SELECT` interno agrupa os documentos por `nf` e escolhe apenas os que tenham o maior `id` dentro de cada grupo, assim sendo trazendo apenas o último registro de cada `nf`. O `SELECT` externo procura então pelos documentos com esses `id`s e filtra apenas os que estiverem com status "excluído". Como resultado, você vai ter apenas os registros que são os últimos de cada NF, desde que esses sejam excluídos.

Editado: O companheiro Rovann Linhalis colocou isso no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b9af07/15).

Comment: acredito já estar respondido... coloquei no sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b9af07/15

Comment: @RovannLinhalis Muito obrigado. :)

Comment: A funçao TOP não ajudaria também?

Comment: @RenatoSilva Acho que usar um `TOP 1` com um `ORDER BY` provavelmente funcionaria também.

Comment: Cara, tu me ajudou e muito aqui, rodou certinho, era isso mesmo que eu queria.